# Embedding Checkout on Laravel Blade

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-blade

I'm trying to display an embedded checkout form from Stripe (https://stripe.com/docs/checkout). I notice that if I place the embedded code between `@section('content')` and `@endsection`, it will not display the form when I click the **Pay with card** button. However, if I remove `@section('content')` or place the embedded code outside of it, then it will display the form perfectly, however, this will break the structure of my layout.

**index.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Billing</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                <h1>Stripe</h1>

                //EMBEDDED CODE STARTS HERE
                <form action="/your-server-side-code" method="POST">
                    <script
                        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                        data-key="pk_test_sTxf2K6z6oemUXlC0NRcowxO"
                        data-amount="2000"
                        data-name="Demo Site"
                        data-description="2 widgets"
                        data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
                        data-locale="auto"
                        data-zip-code="true"
                        data-currency="gbp">
                    </script>
                </form>
                //EMBEDDED CODE ENDS HERE


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Thanks!

EDITED:
layout.app

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <!-- Branding Image -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                        {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        &nbsp;
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                            Logout
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="{{ route('home') }}">Home</a>

                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        @yield('content')
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add the content of `layouts.app` view.

Comment: @Camilo I have added that in the post. It's the default laravel layouts

Comment: What happens if you add some dummy text inside `@section('content') ... @endsection`? Does it show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out what's the problem, it's because the `<script>` tag conflict with Vue components.

**So there are two solutions:**

1) Create a duplicate layout without the Vue element identifier `<div id="app"></div>`

or

2) Create a script tag using the mount() hook in Vue component.

```
createStripeScript () {
        const script = document.createElement('script')
        script.src = 'https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js'
        script.onload = () => this.initStripe()
        document.body.appendChild(script)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with Laravel 8 and the vue scaffolding. If you alter the script tags from `<script>` to `<script type="application/javascript">` or placing the script tag at the end of the file after the vue components have loaded worked also.